# Problem with bézier curve changing to mesh

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I tried to make a pawn from a reference image with the bézier curve and when I converted it to a mesh object and spun it, there is this unwanted edge running down the middle.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: **1 -** Why did you convert to mesh? **2 -** How did you spin it? **3 -** Did you weld the ends?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm guessing he made the profile, converted the curve to mesh, then spun it to make the piece.

Comment: I suppose so but how was it spun? Screw modifier on a mesh? Screw modifier on a curve? Spin operator in Edit Mode? Bevel object in a bezier circle? So many methods, so little answers... :)

Comment: Those likely are doubles which are vertices in the same place but having differently orienting normal vectors, hence difference in shading. If this is a mesh already try selecting all and removing doubles

Answer (score 1):

When you spin 360°, start and end point do not get joined automatically. So what you have are two sets of vertices sitting pretty exactly on top of each other. That won't show with solid shading (without a subsurf), but as you see, with smooth shading, it does.

The left cylinder is clean and you can see the highlighted edges on both sides while the right cylinder shows problems by only having the right half of the edges selected.

The remedy is to select the doubled verts (or all of your mesh if there are no necessary doubles somewhere) and hit <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>, remove doubles. All the verts that are closer than the tool's threshold will get merged into one.

On occasion it's also necessary to recalculate the normals by selecting everything and hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

[image: seamless]